# Single view for all the Grids in MVC

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a requirement like display many of collections in a HTML table format like mentioned below.

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1 Heading</th>
            <!--More column headings-->
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.MyCollection)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.PropertyName</td>
            <!--More properties-->
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
    <!--Add footer for totals-->
</table>
```

I will not specify the view model property names explicitly. I wanted to pass any type of collections to view that will need to generate a HTML table for me.
Please suggest better way of doing it.

Comment: So you want to use reflection in your view to dynamically read model properties and display them?  That sounds like it's going to be *very* error-prone and difficult to support.  If your models share a common structure then you can have your view bind to an interface and display that structure.  But what's the actual problem being solved here?  What's wrong with having views bind to specific model types?

Comment: If you don't want to work with Reflection, another option is to use System.Data.DataTable as ViewModel

Comment: How do you propose to dynamically generate column headings by using reflection or generics to accept the Model? It seems that your approach isn't going to be particularly _safe_, and I wouldn't say that it's recommended to use reflection at the presentation layer of any application. A lot of the times more code is better than less code.

Comment: Actually I am trying to use this view to all my reports. I tried to use dynamic model but unable to get column headings and data in my view. `dynamic mymodel = new ExpandoObject();
            mymodel.ReportTitle = "Sample Report";
            mymodel.ReportData = GetReport1();`

Comment: Look at DataTable as QuietNaN suggested, this will be the least painful way of doing so. But as others have pointed out - this is generally a very bad idea, and just lazy really....

Comment: @QuietNaN Thanks for your suggestion. DataTable  working for my need.